# Using Taglib in CMake project without installing it

Tags: cmake, taglib

I am making a CMake project and the objective is to produce an executable, on either Windows or Unix (but not macOS), by statically linking or by directly using the source code of the third party library (Which is Taglib). I am looking into doing something as simple as that.

```
    git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/MyGitAccount/MyProject.git
    cd MyProject
    cmake .
    make
```

Here's are some details about my CMake project:

My project repository has a reference as a submodule to the Taglib repository.
Consider that Git, CMake and the compiler toolchain (build-essential or MinGW) are installed by default.

**Project Tree Structure**

```
    ProjectName/
    |-- Preload.cmake
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- src/
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- main.cpp
    |-- taglib/
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- taglib/ (This folder is a submodule to my repository. It repository can be found here: 
                     https://github.com/taglib/taglib)
            |-- CMakeLists.txt
            |-- ConfigureChecks.cmake
            |-- cmake_uninstall.cmake.in
            |-- config.h.cmake
            |-- taglib-config.cmake
            |-- taglib-config.cmd.cmake
            |-- taglib.pc.cmake
            |-- cmake/
                |-- modules/
                    |-- FindCppUnit.cmake/
                    |-- MacroEnsureVersion.cmake/
```

**ProjectName/Preload.cmake**

```
    if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
        set (CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
    endif()
    if(WIN32)
        set (CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW Makefiles" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
    endif()
```

**ProjectName/CMakeLists.txt**

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    project(ProjectName)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
    add_subdirectory(taglib)
    # add_subdirectory(src)   # In comment for debugging purpose
```

**ProjectName/taglib/CMakeLists.txt**

```
    set(taglib_DIR ./taglib)
    find_package(taglib CONFIG) 
    if (Taglib_FOUND)
      message("Found!")
    else()
      message("Not Found...")
    endif()
```

**ProjectName/src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
    file(GLOB sources "*.c" "*.cpp")
    file(GLOB headers "*.h" "*.hpp")
    add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${sources} ${headers})
    target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${Taglib_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${Taglib_LIBRARIES})
```

Then, when running "cmake ." in "MyProject/", I obtain this error (On Windows 10).

```
    C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\MyProject>cmake .
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    CMake Error at taglib/taglib/taglib-config.cmake:4:
      Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "{".
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      taglib/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


    CMake Error at taglib/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
      find_package Error reading CMake code from
      "C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/MyProject/taglib/./taglib/taglib-config.cmake".


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/MyProject/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I also tried to use one of the "FindTaglib.cmake" files that I have found while googling.
I have successively placed those files in "MyProject/cmake/modules/ and set the variable "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH" but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Do not do in-source builds with `cmake .`. _Always_ do out-of-source builds with `cmake -S . -B /path/to/somewhere/else`.

Comment: Despite the name, the file [taglib-config.cmake](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/blob/master/taglib-config.cmake) is NOT a CMake script which can be used by `find_package`. This is actually a shell script, which is installed with name `taglib-config`. And, as you include the other project via `add_subdirectory`, there is no needs to use `find_package`: you have already access to the project's targets. E.g. you could link with `tag` library target. But do not forget to add include directories, as in the beginning of the script: https://github.com/taglib/taglib/blob/master/taglib/CMakeLists.txt